# Stacked Area Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some example data attached, I want to make a stacked area plot with the ASVid being the different colors, and the RepCode being the unique sample identifier or date (day.month.year) on the x axis. Then it should add up to 100% so that it is completely filled in. I am having issues getting my dates to be ordered correctly and getting the graph to look correct. So my plot ends up looking all garbled and I have tried to format the days various ways (year.month.day or different formatting in R) but it hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated.

previously I have attempted the following code:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=t,y=val,group=var,fill=var)) + geom_area(position="fill")
```

This image is what I want to end up with, with the various colors being my ASVid column and the y-axis being Mean (which is proportional so it should equal 100) I could either calculate that proportion in the code for the figure or before running the code...
[image]

```
ASVid   day.month.year  Mean
B1000072    16.01.2015  4
B1000676    16.01.2015  5
B1003168    16.01.2015  5
B1016436    16.01.2015  4
B1001873    16.01.2015  3
B1001931    16.01.2015  2
B1000161    16.01.2015  5
B1001289    16.01.2015  5
B1004651    16.01.2015  2
B1000191    16.01.2015  5
B1000278    16.01.2015  9.00E+00
B1001292    16.01.2015  8
B1002209    16.01.2015  7
B1002593    16.01.2015  6.00E+00
B1003600    16.01.2015  5.00E+00
B1003388    16.01.2015  4
B1003628    16.01.2015  3.00E+00
B1005794    16.01.2015  2.00E+00
B1006374    16.01.2015  1.00E+00
B1005605    16.01.2015  1.00E+00
B1006940    16.01.2015  1.00E+00
B1034395    16.01.2015  1.00E+00
B1001633    16.01.2015  1
B1011183    16.01.2015  1
B1002990    16.01.2015  1
B1004756    16.01.2015  1
B1003006    16.01.2015  2
B1006056    16.01.2015  3
B1011591    16.01.2015  3.00E+00
B1001310    6.06.2014   4
B1003643    6.06.2014   5
B1000408    6.06.2014   5
B1002960    6.06.2014   4
B1001336    6.06.2014   3
B1003763    6.06.2014   2
B1000006    6.06.2014   5
B1000105    6.06.2014   5
B1000843    6.06.2014   2
B1002710    6.06.2014   5
B1013163    6.06.2014   9.00E+00
B1000479    6.06.2014   8
B1001687    6.06.2014   7
B1002223    6.06.2014   6.00E+00
B1009009    6.06.2014   5.00E+00
B1010218    6.06.2014   4
B1001037    6.06.2014   3.00E+00
B1001049    6.06.2014   2.00E+00
B1002384    6.06.2014   1.00E+00
B1002556    6.06.2014   1.00E+00
B1003363    6.06.2014   1.00E+00
B1003380    6.06.2014   1.00E+00
B1004762    6.06.2014   1
B1008036    6.06.2014   1
B1008649    6.06.2014   1
B1012788    6.06.2014   1
B1013162    6.06.2014   2
B1000054    6.06.2014   3
B1003433    6.06.2014   3.00E+00
B1019886    6.06.2014   0
B1000294    6.06.2014   0
B1000471    6.06.2014   0
B1000935    6.06.2014   0
B1002742    6.06.2014   0
B1003964    6.06.2014   0
B1004377    6.06.2014   0
B1006053    6.06.2014   0
B1013830    6.06.2014   0
B1021000    6.06.2014   0
B1001893    9.01.2015   2
B1001048    9.01.2015   5
B1000100    9.01.2015   5
B1000920    9.01.2015   2
B1001049    9.01.2015   5
B1003817    9.01.2015   9.00E+00
B1001037    9.01.2015   8
B1000441    9.01.2015   7
B1001507    9.01.2015   6.00E+00
B1002556    9.01.2015   5.00E+00
B1001686    9.01.2015   4
B1001598    9.01.2015   3.00E+00
B1002552    9.01.2015   5.00E+00
B1002787    9.01.2015   7.00E+00
B1002858    9.01.2015   7.00E+00
B1002916    9.01.2015   3.50E+00
B1003926    9.01.2015   5.50E+00
B1004598    9.01.2015   2
B1004947    9.01.2015   3
B1005691    9.01.2015   3
B1004172    9.01.2015   1
B1006246    9.01.2015   2
B1000102    5.12.2014   3
B1001635    5.12.2014   2
B1000511    5.12.2014   3
B1000361    5.12.2014   3
B1002435    5.12.2014   1
B1008707    5.12.2014   2
B1000092    5.12.2014   3
B1001610    5.12.2014   2
B1002293    5.12.2014   3
B1001977    5.12.2014   3
B1002522    5.12.2014   7
B1002614    5.12.2014   8
B1002750    5.12.2014   0
B1003983    5.12.2014   9
B1004407    5.12.2014   5
B1020999    5.12.2014   7
B1001651    5.12.2014   1
B1000254    5.12.2014   7
B1008692    5.12.2014   9
B1002787    5.12.2014   4
B1017385    5.12.2014   3
B1000996    5.12.2014   3
B1001321    5.12.2014   2
B1002858    5.12.2014   2
B1005632    5.12.2014   3
B1008044    5.12.2014   2
B1029767    5.12.2014   3
B1000365    29.04.2016  8
B1000157    29.04.2016  5
B1001935    29.04.2016  2
B1000684    29.04.2016  6
B1000417    29.04.2016  8
B1000400    29.04.2016  5
B1000591    29.04.2016  6
B1001351    29.04.2016  7
B1002861    29.04.2016  2
B1001150    29.04.2016  3
B1003145    29.04.2016  2
B1004872    29.04.2016  9
B1000650    29.04.2016  6
B1003404    29.04.2016  6
B1000166    29.04.2016  10
B1000237    29.04.2016  8
B1002435    29.04.2016  4
B1006836    29.04.2016  3
```

Comment: Hi Anna, I checked you data and you have 129 values for ASVID, are you sure you want to plot all of them?

Comment: Yes I do want to plot all the ASVids, I know that they will be hard to distinguish, but I will deal with that later by maybe lumping some of them together, but for now I think since the data does go into a stacked bar plot correctly and look good, I should be able to make it into a stacked area plot looking good...(as pictured above with what I desire)--but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two approaches using `ggplot2`. Your data is large and has plenty of `ASVid` values. The area plot can be created but I think the issue would be the large legend and the lack of values. Here the code for an area plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code for data format
df$day.month.year <- as.Date(df$day.month.year,'%d.%m.%Y')
#Plot option 1
ggplot(df, aes(x=day.month.year,y=Mean,fill=ASVid))+
  geom_area(position="fill")
```

This would be the output (see the not elegant legend):

[image]

A second approach would be using a stacked `geom_bar()` like this:

```
#Plot option 2
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(day.month.year),y=Mean,fill=ASVid))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'stack')
```

Despite the large legend, values can be seen better. Here the output:

[image]

You can choose any of the options.

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ASVid = c("B1000072", "B1000676", "B1003168", 
"B1016436", "B1001873", "B1001931", "B1000161", "B1001289", "B1004651", 
"B1000191", "B1000278", "B1001292", "B1002209", "B1002593", "B1003600", 
"B1003388", "B1003628", "B1005794", "B1006374", "B1005605", "B1006940", 
"B1034395", "B1001633", "B1011183", "B1002990", "B1004756", "B1003006", 
"B1006056", "B1011591", "B1001310", "B1003643", "B1000408", "B1002960", 
"B1001336", "B1003763", "B1000006", "B1000105", "B1000843", "B1002710", 
"B1013163", "B1000479", "B1001687", "B1002223", "B1009009", "B1010218", 
"B1001037", "B1001049", "B1002384", "B1002556", "B1003363", "B1003380", 
"B1004762", "B1008036", "B1008649", "B1012788", "B1013162", "B1000054", 
"B1003433", "B1019886", "B1000294", "B1000471", "B1000935", "B1002742", 
"B1003964", "B1004377", "B1006053", "B1013830", "B1021000", "B1001893", 
"B1001048", "B1000100", "B1000920", "B1001049", "B1003817", "B1001037", 
"B1000441", "B1001507", "B1002556", "B1001686", "B1001598", "B1002552", 
"B1002787", "B1002858", "B1002916", "B1003926", "B1004598", "B1004947", 
"B1005691", "B1004172", "B1006246", "B1000102", "B1001635", "B1000511", 
"B1000361", "B1002435", "B1008707", "B1000092", "B1001610", "B1002293", 
"B1001977", "B1002522", "B1002614", "B1002750", "B1003983", "B1004407", 
"B1020999", "B1001651", "B1000254", "B1008692", "B1002787", "B1017385", 
"B1000996", "B1001321", "B1002858", "B1005632", "B1008044", "B1029767", 
"B1000365", "B1000157", "B1001935", "B1000684", "B1000417", "B1000400", 
"B1000591", "B1001351", "B1002861", "B1001150", "B1003145", "B1004872", 
"B1000650", "B1003404", "B1000166", "B1000237", "B1002435", "B1006836"
), day.month.year = structure(c(16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 
16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 
16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 
16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16451, 16227, 16227, 16227, 
16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 
16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 
16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 
16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 16227, 
16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 
16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 
16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 
16409, 16409, 16409, 16409, 16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 
16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 16920, 
16920, 16920, 16920, 16920), class = "Date"), Mean = c(4, 5, 
5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 
4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 5, 7, 7, 3.5, 5.5, 
2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 7, 8, 0, 9, 5, 7, 
1, 7, 9, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 5, 2, 6, 8, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 
2, 9, 6, 6, 10, 8, 4, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -135L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't understand why the plot looks great when using a bar plot, which I can also get to work on my end, but then when trying to get it to be a stacked bar plot it doesn't show all the results? It just has 2 weird colors and they aren't the way I would have expected for the dataset

Comment: @Anna Please check the structure of your data and also the dates.